# C++ smart pointers polymophism

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism, smart-pointers

I am quite new to smart pointer so sorry if my question seems naive to some of you.
Here is an example of what i want to do:

```
using namespace std;

class Base
{
protected:
   int m_Property;
public:
   virtual function() {...;}
}

class DerivedA : public Base
{
public:
   virtual function() {second implementation...;}
   virtual functionA() {...;}
}

class DerivedB : virtual public Base, public DerivedA
{
public:
   virtual functionB() {...;}
}

void main()
{
   map<int, shared_ptr<Base>> myMap;

   shared_ptr<Base> object_ptr1 =  shared_ptr<Base>(new Base());
   shared_ptr<Base> object_ptr2 =  shared_ptr<Base>(new DerivedA());
   shared_ptr<Base> object_ptr3 =  shared_ptr<Base>(new DerivedB());

   myMap.insert(pair<int, shared_ptr<Base>>(1,object_ptr1));
   myMap.insert(pair<int, shared_ptr<Base>>(2,object_ptr2));
   myMap.insert(pair<int, shared_ptr<Base>>(3,object_ptr3));

   // What i want to do (cause I know for sure that object_ptr3 points to a DerivedB object):
   object_ptr3->functionB();
}
```

Let say that i have extracted a shared pointer from myMap (lets call it myPointer), and that i want to use DerivedB specific (but not inherited virtual) functions.
The compiled does not understand cause it thinks that myPointer (or object_ptr3 in the above example) is of Base type.

I tried casting it with static_pointer_cast and dynamic_pointer_cast (which in some cases does not work)...
Any better id for handling these king of situations.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `dynamic_pointer_cast` or `static_pointer_cast` should work as expected. Can you show us how you used them and where it fails?

Comment: Is `shared` a new template or just a typo?

Comment: Here is the compiler message:
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\memory(369): error C2635: cannot convert a 'Base*' to a 'DerivedC*'; conversion from a virtual base class is implied

The problem is I have multiple inheritance: DerivedC inherits from Base and from DerivedA. So I used virtual to avoid problems with the "Base" class double inheritance

Comment: Change the inheritance in the classes from `public` to `virtual` just to see what happens.

Comment: I see no `DerivedC` class in the source above, so I'm not terribly surprised by a failure to convert.

Comment: Ok just changed the above code. So here is the compiler error:

1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\memory(369): error C2635: cannot convert a 'Base*' to a 'DerivedC*'; conversion from a virtual base class is implied

Comment: Why you are inheriting from Base if you're inheriting from A, which already inherits from Base? I'm not sure if this should be legal :o

Comment: I did this so that I know that all my DerivedXX classes are of Base type. That is the reason why i used the "virtual" inheritance keyword

Comment: Ok, I think i am getting closer to the answers searching about Downcasting and Diamond inheritance.
Thanks to all

Comment: For diamond inheritance, you have to make all inheritance virtual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dynamic_pointer_cast` must work for this case. Maybe you did something wrong while casting.
It should look like this:

```
std::shared_ptr<Base> base(new Base);
std::shared_ptr<Derived> derived = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Derived>(base);
```

Looking at your code again, the problem might be that you're calling `object_ptr3.functionB();` with a `.` instead of a `->`. `object_ptr3` is a `shared_ptr`, so the `.` operator will access members of the `shared_ptr` class rather than your derived class.

Also, is `shared` a `shared_ptr`?

Comment: yes, shared is a shared_ptr. I am editing my question to change this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. These are typos in my post. The use I have made from shared_ptr is the same as in your code